# Error while acessing private members in member functions

Tags: c++

Im having an strange issue in a class that im developing. When I try to acess some private members of the class inside a class member function I receive the following error

```
error: 'double** LinAlg::Matrix<double>mat' is private
```

Some samples of the code that generate it:

```
//Class private declaratios

template <typename T>
class C
{
     public:
     template <typename U>
     C<T> operator+(C<U> rhs);

     private:
     T member;
}

template <typename T> template <typename U>
C<T> C::operator+(C<U> rhs)
{
     return this->member + rhs.member;
}
```

Sorry for the trouble, hope you can help me.

@Edit: I get the error in some member functions that use two templates for then.

Comment: That method isn't part of the class. Wouldn't you have to `friend` it to allow access?

Comment: It isn't really possible to tell what's going on from the sample code.  Take a loot at the help page: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why it isnt? The method is declared inside class scope. Im missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit it.

Comment: I'm guessing when you get the error the `T` parameter for `this` is something other than `double`. `C<Foo>` and `C<Bar>` are different types, they cannot access each other's private members. You could add `template<typename> friend class C` to the class declaration, smells a bit funny though.

Comment: It makes sense. Thinking im acessing a private member with a member function of another class.

Comment: If U is of a different type of T, then the private member of a different class type is inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

I get it! Thanks for the info the comments, its like user657267 and George Houpis said. If T and U are from different types, so, they're from different classes, said that, what i need it was to offer some other ways to acess the private members, something like this may help:

```
template<typename T>
class C
{
     public:
     template<typename U>
     C<T> operator+(C<U> rhs);
     T getMember() {return this->member;};

     private:
     T member;
}

template<typename T> template<typename U>
C<T> C::operator+(C<U> rhs)
{
     return this->member + rhs.getMember();
}
```